# Can I create Docker container in Linux to use it on Unix?

Tags: python, linux, docker, unix, cx-oracle

In our company, all the machines are Linux or windows. But the customer has a Unix system. Can I create a docker container in Linux then use it on Unix. I want the docker file to contain python with cx_oracle and pandas libraries And put them in the UNIX machine. Just want to make sure that the environment is working by using cx_oracle to connect on Oracle DB on the Unix machine.

> What will be exactly the code or docker file using cx_oracle and
> pandas libraries that should be run on Unix and making sure that the
> environment is working by using cx_oracle to connect on Oracle DB on
> the Unix machine?

Comment: "Unix" is not nearly specific enough to say. You'll have to figure out exactly what the machine is running, whether it supports Docker at all, and if so, what kind of Docker images it's capable of running.

Comment: @that other guy its difficult to know that from the client but I can try. But isn't there any generic way to do so like just have a docker file using cx_oracle and pandas libraries and then put them as a script or docker image in unix and then execute or something like that?

Comment: There's no generic way to run Docker images on Unix. It's a pretty Linux-centric technology, and Windows/macOS users typically do it through emulation. If the mystery OS doesn't support Docker then obviously it's not a good approach.

Answer (score 0):

It's always edge case differences between OSs that cause app porting problems: signal handling, subtle file system differences, etc.  How cx_Oracle behaves won't differ much between different OSs - except library initialization.  Make sure you test properly on the exact deployment environment. That way you will know exactly how to do the app & Oracle Client install, how the network needs to be configured, how the app needs to be tuned (e.g. best values for `arraysize` and `prefetchrows` for queries), etc.

In your case, it's the OS that Python will run on that matters, since this can be (and often is) different to the OS that the DB runs on.  I think you should test on the exact customer environment, not in some container (even if that works) or virtualized setup.

Find the details and update your original question if you need more help.